# Incomplete structured construct

Tags: asp.net-mvc, f#

i am new with f# , will be great if some 1 can help , nearly half a day gone solving this problem Thank you

```
module Certificate =
        type T = {
            Id: int
            IsECert: bool
            IsPrintCert: bool
            CertifiedBy: string  
            Categories: Category.T list
}

let createPending now toZonedDateTime toBeCertifiedByName (job: Models.Job.T) (certificateType: Models.CertificateType.T) (pendingCertificate: Models.PendingCertificate.T) visualization  (categories: Category.T list)  = 
            let forCompletion = Models.PendingCertificate.getCertificateForCompletion pendingCertificate
             {
              Id = forCompletion.Id |> CertificateId.toInt
              IsECert = Models.PendingCertificate.isECertificate pendingCertificate
              IsPrintCert = Models.PendingCertificate.isPrintCertificate pendingCertificate
              CertifiedBy = toBeCertifiedByName 
Categories = categories}
```

i am getting an error in "Incomplete structured construct at or before this point"

Comment: To help understand the situation, could you add a brief description of what you're trying to accomplish with the code snippet as well as the full error?

Answer (score 2):

Your formatting is all off. I will assume here that this is just a result of posting to StackOverflow, and your actual code is well indented.

The error comes from the definition of `createPending`: this function does not have a result. All its body consists of defining a `forCompletion` value, but there is nothing after it. Here's a simpler example that has the same problem:

```
let f x =
   let y = 5
```

This function will produce the same error, because it also doesn't have a result. In F#, every function has to return *something*. The body cannot contain only definitions of helper functions or values. For example, I could fix my broken function above like this:

```
let f x =
   let y = 5
   x + y
```

This function first defines a helper value `y`, then adds it to its argument `x`, and returns the result.

```
> f 2
> 7
>
> f 0
> 5
```

How exactly you need to fix your function depends on what exactly you want it to mean. I can't help you here, because you haven't provided that information.